# Install miniconda Python 2.7

Tags: python

I am trying to install `miniconda` Python 2.7 on ubuntu 12.04. 
I have already written this:

```
if ! [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then touch ~/.bash_profile; fi
if ! [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then touch ~/.bashrc; fi
if ! grep -q "source ~/.bashrc" ~/.bash_profile; then echo 'if [ -f    ~/.bashrc ]; then source ~/.bashrc; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile; fi
```

then I use:

```
bash Miniconda-*.sh
```

but a process starts and never ends.
I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: What's `miniconda` and how did you install it?

Comment: @David, there is an answer below that answers your question too!  **;-)**

Comment: @DavidFoerster read my answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this simple steps in a terminal:

```
cd
```

for 64-bit:

```
wget -c http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

for 32-bit

```
wget -c http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86.sh
```

I will now refer to the 64-bit version.

```
chmod +x Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
./Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

The following steps you have to go through:

```
Welcome to Miniconda 3.10.1 (by Continuum Analytics, Inc.)

In order to continue the installation process, please review the license
agreement.
Please, press ENTER to continue
>>>
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

read the license (or not ;)) and

<kbd>Q</kbd>

then type `yes`

```
Do you approve the license terms? [yes|no]
[no] >>> yes
```

accept the path or enter a new path

```
Miniconda will now be installed into this location:
/home/<your_username>/miniconda

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/<your_username>/miniconda] >>>
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
PREFIX=/home/<your_username>/miniconda
installing: python-2.7.9-3 ...
installing: conda-env-2.1.4-py27_0 ...
installing: openssl-1.0.1k-1 ...
installing: pycosat-0.6.1-py27_0 ...
installing: pyyaml-3.11-py27_0 ...
installing: readline-6.2-2 ...
installing: requests-2.6.0-py27_0 ...
installing: sqlite-3.8.4.1-1 ...
installing: system-5.8-2 ...
installing: tk-8.5.18-0 ...
installing: yaml-0.1.4-0 ...
installing: zlib-1.2.8-0 ...
installing: conda-3.10.1-py27_0 ...
Python 2.7.9 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
creating default environment...
installation finished.
Do you wish the installer to prepend the Miniconda install location
to PATH in your /home/<your_username>/.bashrc ? [yes|no]
[no] >>>
```

type `yes`

```
Prepending PATH=/home/<your_username>/miniconda/bin to PATH in /home/<your_username>/.bashrc
A backup will be made to: /home/<your_username>/.bashrc-miniconda.bak


For this change to become active, you have to open a new terminal.

Thank you for installing Miniconda!
```

Thats all.

Close your terminal and restart or `source /home/<your_username>/.bashrc`

Start `conda` and you will see something like this:

```
$ conda
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...

conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications, environments and
packages.

positional arguments:

[...]
```

Now you can start with eg. installing `numpy`:

```
conda install numpy
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I read licence and type "yes" a process starts and never ends and following steps never happens.

Comment: when I type yes an endless stream of y starts and it does not end until I use ctrl+C

Comment: Funny, hmm probably not.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. You should upgrade your Ubuntu.

Comment: finally I installed python, now I am trying to install a toolbox but this error occurs:

Comment: I can't see an error?

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: before that there are some other errors: bashrc seems to be called in .bash_profile
>> . ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
/bin/sh: 13: /home/shokufeh/.bashrc: shopt: not found
/bin/sh: 21: /home/shokufeh/.bashrc: shopt: not found
/bin/sh: 105: /home/shokufeh/.bashrc: shopt: not found
/bin/sh: 28: /etc/bash_completion: [[: not found
/bin/sh: 34: /etc/bash_completion: [[: not found
/bin/sh: 51: /etc/bash_completion: Bad substitution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./installer.py", line 883, in <module>
    Installer()

Comment: First, is miniconda installed, could you read: "Thank you for installing Miniconda!"?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.

Comment: Then it would be fair if you mark my answer and give me an upvote. Then you should create a new question. This is good for your reputation. To answer new questions in comments is too confusing. :c)

Comment: And than, give me the link to your new question. ;)

Comment: ok, sorry. I am new to ubuntu and this site and not familiar with how it works! I will do it. :D

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer. :-/

Comment: No problem. Create a new question and I give you an upvote. Then you have enough

Comment: this is the link to my question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/619924/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable

Comment: Found it and upvoted :)