# How can I download and install miniconda?

Tags: python, 20.04, anaconda

I'm a brand new linux user, so please let me know if I'm missing something super obvious here.

I'm using the newest release of ubuntu, 20 04.

I've tried downloading miniconda from their website (couldn't find it in the software app),and it goes into the downloads folder like I'd expect, but i'm not sure what to do from there. I've opened it a few times but it just opens in text editor.

I've noticed python 3 is already installed somewhere, altough I can't seem to find the acual location. Regarless, I can poen a python shell in the terminal, I'm not sure if already having python would be interfering with anything.

I haven't messed around with the file system much or anything, I've just downloaded gnome tweaks and did a few personalization things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install miniconda Python 2.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615700/install-miniconda-python-2-7)

Comment: I don't know `miniconda` so can only offer generic advice, I usually look for a clue when I download software (and usually opt for standard Ubuntu repositories if I can; did you enable the extra repos? as by default they are disabled). If there is no clues on the site, I'll ask the system what type of file it is (eg. `file /path/unknown`) so regardless of any extension (which can be misleading or wrong if malicious) the system gives me clues. From here the result depend on what results I got..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the link given below and install the software:

1. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot, one more question though. I got miniconda installed, but it said something about it being started in the base environment or something.I copied he commnd it gave me to undo that, but now when I start the terminal I'm getting th word (base) t the left of my prompt, and I was wondering what that meant.

Answer (score 4):

Python 3.7

**64 bits**

`wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`

`bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`

**32 bits**

`wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh`

`bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh`

> Close your terminal and open again:

```
conda list
conda init fish
```

For make update:

```
conda update conda
```